# MS Access SQL with two SUM Function

Tags: ms-access, group-by, sum, subquery

I have a "`TableA`" with fields "`A, B, C, Bytes, Entrada_Saida`" and need to return in the same query a `Sum(Bytes)` when `"Entrada_Saida = Entrada"` and another when `"Entrada_Saida = Saida"`, grouping by `A, B, C, Entrada_Saida, Bytes`.

Tried but keep´n on "At most one record can be returned by this subquery" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return both sums in the same row, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  A, B, C,
  SUM(IIF(Entrada_Saida='Entrada',Bytes,0)) Bytes_Entradas,
  SUM(IIF(Entrada_Saida='Saida',Bytes,0)) Bytes_Saidas
FROM
  Yourtable
GROUP BY
  A, B, C
```